# Using apache poi 4.0 export radar-chart.It's something wrong, when it was opened with ms excel 2016

Tags: excel, apache-poi, radar-chart

Error Prompt:  Excel was able to open the file by repairing or removing the unreadable content. Removed Part: /xl/drawings/drawing1.xml

code:

```
private void genRadarChart(XSSFSheet sheet, String sheetName, int dataStartRow, int dataEndRow) {
    XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
    XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, dataStartRow - 1, 2, dataStartRow + 9);
    XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);

    CTChart ctChart = chart.getCTChart();
    ctChart.addNewAutoTitleDeleted().setVal(false);

    CTPlotArea ctPlotArea = ctChart.addNewPlotArea();
    ctPlotArea.addNewLayout();

    CTRadarChart ctRadarChart = ctPlotArea.addNewRadarChart();
    //
    ctRadarChart.addNewAxId().setVal(123456);
    ctRadarChart.addNewAxId().setVal(123457);
    // 
    CTDLbls ctdLbls = ctRadarChart.addNewDLbls();
    ctdLbls.addNewShowLegendKey().setVal(false);
    ctdLbls.addNewShowVal().setVal(false);
    ctdLbls.addNewShowCatName().setVal(false);
    ctdLbls.addNewShowSerName().setVal(false);
    ctdLbls.addNewShowPercent().setVal(false);
    ctdLbls.addNewShowBubbleSize().setVal(false);
    // 
    ctRadarChart.addNewRadarStyle().setVal(STRadarStyle.MARKER);
    ctRadarChart.addNewVaryColors().setVal(false);

    CTRadarSer ctRadarSer = ctRadarChart.addNewSer();
    ctRadarSer.addNewIdx().setVal(0);
    ctRadarSer.addNewOrder().setVal(0);
    CTLineProperties ctLineProperties = ctRadarSer.addNewSpPr().addNewLn();
    ctLineProperties.addNewRound();
    ctLineProperties.addNewSolidFill().addNewSchemeClr().setVal(STSchemeColorVal.Enum.forString("accent1"));
    // 
    ctRadarSer.addNewCat().addNewStrRef().setF(sheetName + "!$C$" + dataStartRow + ":$C$" + dataEndRow);
    ctRadarSer.addNewVal().addNewNumRef().setF(sheetName + "!$D$" + dataStartRow + ":$D$" + dataEndRow);
    ctRadarSer.addNewMarker().addNewSpPr().addNewBlipFill();

    CTCatAx ctCatAx = ctPlotArea.addNewCatAx();
    ctCatAx.addNewAxId().setVal(123456);
    ctCatAx.addNewScaling().addNewOrientation().setVal(STOrientation.Enum.forString("minMax"));
    ctCatAx.addNewDelete().setVal(false);
    ctCatAx.addNewAxPos().setVal(STAxPos.B);
    ctCatAx.addNewCrossAx().setVal(123457);
    ctCatAx.addNewMajorTickMark().setVal(STTickMark.NONE);
    ctCatAx.addNewMinorTickMark().setVal(STTickMark.NONE);
    ctCatAx.addNewTickLblPos().setVal(STTickLblPos.Enum.forString("nextTo"));


    CTValAx ctValAx = ctPlotArea.addNewValAx();
    ctValAx.addNewAxId().setVal(123457);
    ctValAx.addNewScaling().addNewOrientation().setVal(STOrientation.Enum.forString("minMax"));
    ctValAx.addNewDelete().setVal(false);
    ctValAx.addNewAxPos().setVal(STAxPos.L);
    ctValAx.addNewCrossAx().setVal(123456);
    ctValAx.addNewMajorTickMark().setVal(STTickMark.NONE);
    ctValAx.addNewMinorTickMark().setVal(STTickMark.NONE);
    ctValAx.addNewTickLblPos().setVal(STTickLblPos.Enum.forString("nextTo"));

    CTShapeProperties ctShapeProperties = ctValAx.addNewMajorGridlines().addNewSpPr();
    CTLineProperties ctLineProperties1 = ctShapeProperties.addNewLn();
    ctLineProperties1.setW(9525);
    ctLineProperties1.setCap(STLineCap.FLAT);
    ctLineProperties1.setCmpd(STCompoundLine.SNG);
    ctLineProperties1.setAlgn(STPenAlignment.CTR);

    ctValAx.addNewSpPr().addNewLn().addNewGradFill();

    ctValAx.addNewTxPr().addNewP().addNewPPr().addNewDefRPr().addNewNoFill();
}
```

click repair, the radar-charts(xml) is deleted. thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using `apache poi 4` you should update to `apache poi 4.1.2` and then using the new `XDDF` stuff instead of the low level `CTChart` stuff. This provides [XDDFRadarChartData](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/XDDFRadarChartData.html) and [ChartTypes.RADAR](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/ChartTypes.html#RADAR) already.

I will provide a complete example for how to use:

```java
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

public class RadarChart {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String[] categories = new String[]{"Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat3", "Cat4", "Cat5"};
    Double[] values = new Double[]{1d, 2d, 3d, 4d, 5d};

    try (XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook()) {

      XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("radarchart");

      Row row;
      Cell cell;
      row = sheet.createRow(0);
      cell = row.createCell(1); cell.setCellValue("Series");
      for (int i = 1; i <= categories.length; i++) {
        row = sheet.createRow(i);
        cell = row.createCell(0); cell.setCellValue(categories[i-1]);
        cell = row.createCell(1); cell.setCellValue(values[i-1]);
      }

      XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
      XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 10, 15);

      XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
      chart.setTitleText("Chart title");
      chart.setTitleOverlay(false);

      XDDFChartLegend legend = chart.getOrAddLegend();
      legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.RIGHT);

      XDDFCategoryAxis bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
      //major gridlines of category axis are the cobweb radial lines
      XDDFShapeProperties bottomAxisGridLinesShapeProperties = bottomAxis.getOrAddMajorGridProperties();
      bottomAxisGridLinesShapeProperties.setLineProperties(new XDDFLineProperties(
          new XDDFSolidFillProperties(XDDFColor.from(PresetColor.BLACK))));

      XDDFValueAxis leftAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
      leftAxis.setMajorUnit(1d);
      //left axis line color is needed for radial lines
      XDDFShapeProperties leftAxisShapeProperties = leftAxis.getOrAddShapeProperties();
      leftAxisShapeProperties.setLineProperties(new XDDFLineProperties(
          new XDDFSolidFillProperties(XDDFColor.from(PresetColor.BLACK))));
      //major gridlines of values axis are the cobweb ring lines
      XDDFShapeProperties leftAxisGridLinesShapeProperties = leftAxis.getOrAddMajorGridProperties();
      leftAxisGridLinesShapeProperties.setLineProperties(new XDDFLineProperties(
          new XDDFSolidFillProperties(XDDFColor.from(PresetColor.GRAY))));

      leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);
      leftAxis.setCrossBetween(AxisCrossBetween.BETWEEN);

      XDDFDataSource<String> cat = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange(sheet,
          new CellRangeAddress(1, categories.length, 0, 0));
      XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> val = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet,
          new CellRangeAddress(1, categories.length, 1, 1));

      XDDFChartData data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.RADAR, bottomAxis, leftAxis);
      data.setVaryColors(false);
      XDDFChartData.Series series = data.addSeries(cat, val);
      series.setTitle(sheet.getRow(0).getCell(1).getStringCellValue(), new CellReference(sheet.getRow(0).getCell(1)));
      solidLineSeries(series, PresetColor.BLUE);
      chart.plot(data);

      //radar chart needs to have a radar style set
      XDDFRadarChartData radarChartData = (XDDFRadarChartData) data;
      radarChartData.setStyle(RadarStyle.MARKER);

      // Do not auto delete the title; is necessary for showing title in Calc
      if (chart.getCTChart().getAutoTitleDeleted() == null) chart.getCTChart().addNewAutoTitleDeleted();
      chart.getCTChart().getAutoTitleDeleted().setVal(false);

      try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("ooxml-radar-chart.xlsx")) {
        wb.write(fileOut);
      }
    }
  }

  private static void solidLineSeries(XDDFChartData.Series series, PresetColor color) {
    XDDFSolidFillProperties fill = new XDDFSolidFillProperties(XDDFColor.from(color));
    XDDFLineProperties line = new XDDFLineProperties();
    line.setFillProperties(fill);
    XDDFShapeProperties properties = series.getShapeProperties();
    if (properties == null) {
      properties = new XDDFShapeProperties();
    }
    properties.setLineProperties(line);
    series.setShapeProperties(properties);
  }
}
```